# What is the proper way to inject (via constructor) different types that implement that same interface?

Tags: unity-container

For example, let's say I have an interface 'IFeed' and two concrete types ('Feed1' and 'Feed2') that implement this interface. Now let's say I have a 'FeedManager' type that takes multiple parameters that will get resolved dynamically, two of which are of type 'IFeed' and I'd like both concrete type to be injected via constructor injection, *not* via manual resolve (I only use resolve once at the composition root). I have a feeling that I should be using a factory but I wanted to see what the proper way of doing this might be. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually done via automated DI tools like Unity DI container. You resolve the type with an alias/name and specify that for the parameter in config or otherwise.

Comment: I bumped into a wall when trying to use an alias because it seems that I need to specify the exact constructor signature; I can't seem to tell it that a parameter named 'feed1' should be resolved to this, and paramter 'feed2' should be resolved to that... I would have to fill in all parameters. Anyhow I'm wondering if this is proper design at all.

Comment: Your question doesn't match the answer you have accepted. Maybe a code sample would have helped in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want ALL implementations of IFeed, you can use array syntax in your constructor and then nothing special is needed at type registration time.

```
container.RegisterType<IFeedManager, FeedManager>();
container.RegisterType<IFeed, FeedA>("FeedA"); // The name doesn't matter
container.RegisterType<IFeed, FeedB>("FeedB"); // The name doesn't matter
```

Then the manager constructor...

```
public FeedManager(IFeed[] feeds) {...}
```

or if you want to add a little flare for calling the constructor directly...

```
public FeedManager(params IFeed[] feeds) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to determine the actual concrete instances at runtime, you need to use named type registrations and then tell unity which one you want. So, use a factory method to construct the types required and pass those in as parameter overrides. Unity will use the overrides and resolve any remaining dependencies.

```
 // register the types using named registrations
container.RegisterType<IFeedManager,FeedManager>()
container.RegisterType<IFeed, Feed1>("Feed1")
container.RegisterType<IFeed, Feed2>("Feed2")
```

Assuming your feed manager has the following named constructor parameters

```
class FeedManager : IFeedManager
{
   public FeedManager (IFeed Feed1, IFeed Feed2, string someOtherDependency)
   {
   }
}
```

and create your feed manager:

```
static IFeedManager CreateFeedManager()
{

    ParameterOverride feed1 = new ParameterOverride("Feed1"
                         ,_container.Resolve<IFeed>("feed1"));

    ParameterOverride feed2 = new DependencyOverride("Feed2"
                         ,_container.Resolve<IFeed>("feed2"));

    IFeedManager = _container.Resolve<IFeedManager>(feed1,feed2)

    return IFeedManager;
}
```

Obviously this is overly simplified, but you you insert your own logic to determine which instance is to be resolved and then injected for each of the IFeed instances required by the FeedManager.

Answer (score 0):

With Unity you would do this like so:

```
container.RegisterType<IFeed, Feed1>("Feed1");
container.RegisterType<IFeed, Feed2>("Feed2");
container.RegisterType<FeedManager>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IFeed>("Feed1"),
    new ResolvedParameter<IFeed>("Feed2")));
```

This has now configured Unity so that when it needs to resolve a `FeedManager`, it will resolve Feed1 for the first parameter and Feed2 for the second parameter.